# How get Form data in admin magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have added a button on admin form in magento,when i click  on it i did not get form data,i want functionality like save button.

```
  $this->_addButton('owner', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Change Owner'),
        'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('*/*/owner/id/'.$id) . '\')',
        'class'     => 'save',
    ),1,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your requirement is not clear.Where are you checking the submitted data? If you want to submit the admin form data and receive it in the controller file than you placed the button in the wrong place.It should not be in the Form.php

Comment: I want to update specific value of field in database,when i click on owner button.